# Drop-down menu in processing.js

Tags: drop-down-menu, processing, processing.js

I am a grade 6 student and am working on a science assignment using processing.js.

The user inputs information (about a volcanic eruption) and is provided with an output of some info about this eruption (such as how many casualties there were)

Right now I'm working on the input page - specifically a drop-down menu that picks the type of lava.

When I click on the drop-down box, the other boxes appear but when I try to click out of it, nothing happens.  I bet I've overlooked something really simple here but it won't work. Any other help I could get on this drop-down box would be appreciated.

Here is the snippet of code that draws the menu:

```java
//text boxes----------
rect(95, 30, 66, 22);
rect(95, 65, 66, 22);

fill(255, 255, 255);
textSize(16);

text("ash spread", 5, 47);

text("lava type", 5, 83);

    var draw = function() {

            if (mouseIsPressed && mouseX > 95 && mouseX < 161 && mouseY > 65 && mouseY < 87) {
            ltDropDown = true;
            }

        if (ltDropDown === true) {
            fill(0, 0, 0);

            rect(95, 87, 66, 22);
            rect(95, 109, 66, 22);
            rect(95, 131, 66, 22);
            rect(95, 153, 66, 22);

            fill(255, 255, 255);
            textSize(15);

            text("Basaltic", 100, 92, 66, 22);
            text("Andesitic", 100, 114, 66, 22);
            text("Dacitic", 100, 136, 66, 22);
            text("Rhyolitic", 100, 158, 66, 22);
        }

            if (mouseIsPressed && ltDropDown === true) {
            ltDropDown = false;
            }
        //--------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

In the future, you should really try to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We should be able to copy and paste your code into our own machines to see the same thing as you. You could also consider posting a JSFiddle. It's hard to help if we can't run your code, so try to make it easier for us to help you!

But from the code you have posted, I think I see the problem: when do you ever clear the dropdown menu?

Even after you set `ltDropDown` to `false`, you aren't ever drawing anything else. So the dropdown menu you've already drawn will just stay there.

You might be thinking that Processing automatically clears the canvas every frame, but it doesn't. If you want to do that, you have to call the `background()` function at the beginning of every call to your `draw()` function.

More info can be found in [the reference](http://processingjs.org/reference/background_/).

PS: I assume this is homework and you have to use Processing for your dropdown, but if that's not the case, then you might consider using pure JavaScript to build an HTML dropdown box instead. That'll be a lot easier than doing it yourself, unless the point of the homework is to do it yourself in the first place.